# Why does DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceClass throw a FileNotFound Exception

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have the following snippet of code that is intended to check if I can access Location Services. It builds ok but on the device and emulator I get a FileNotFound Exception on the switch (accessInfo.CurrentStatus) line (there is nothing on Google about this)

```
        var accessInfo = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceClass(DeviceClass.Location);
        accessInfo.AccessChanged += OnAccessChanged;
        switch (accessInfo.CurrentStatus)
        {
            case DeviceAccessStatus.Unspecified:                    
                break;
            case DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed:
                break;
            case DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser:
                break;
            case DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedBySystem:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device stacks from Windows and Windows Phone are not exactly the same in 8.x. Geolocation is one example where they are different, and this manifests itself in this error. You can use the [`Geolocator.LocationStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.locationstatus.aspx) API instead. Note that on Windows Phone, the app is always granted the location capability (it's an install-time prompt) although the user could still turn off location globally.

Comment: Thanks, I carried on researching and I was coming to this conclusion. It's annoying because the sample seems to imply it works for both as do the MSDN docs :( Hopefully this will be fixed in Windows 10

Comment: Any way how to check if the uses has disabled location globally? Other than handling the error thrown when using the GeoLocator?